# i want to pass the js id to params and save to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

after  a form input of first page  .a bootsrap modal appears which have two buttons like one is named as "yes" and second one as "No" ,i want to save the value of yes button to true and no button to false.my view is as follows

```
    <%= form_tag storesignup_is_taxable_path, :method => 
                     :post, :id=>'tax-btn', :remote => true  do  %>

    <div class="md-modal md-effect-10" id="gst_applicable">
    <div class="md-content">
        <h3>GST</h3>
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="gst_tax_apply">
                <p>Does GST applicable to you or your business?
                </p>                    
    <input name="authenticity_token" value="<%= 
            form_authenticity_token %>" type="hidden">


    <input type="hidden" class="form-control otp-input" 
             name='tax_applicable' id='tax_applicable' >

            <button type="submit" class=""  id='tax-btn' ></button>

    <button  class="btn gst_enable" 
         onclick="document.getElementById('tax_applicable').value = 
    '1';document.getElementById('tax-btn').click();"  > Yes</button>

 <button  class="btn gst_dissable" 
 onclick="document.getElementById('tax_applicable').value = 
 '2';document.getElementById('tax-btn').click();">No</button>

            </div>
<button type="button" class="md-close btn btn-close">close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

my controller

```
   def is_taxable
      @data.update_attributes(:tax_applicable => params[:is_taxable])
      @data.save
      render js: ''
  end
```

plz help iam badly stucked and new to rails

Comment: how would `params[:is_taxable]` be populated? You should probably print out the params and see what is in the request first.

Comment: sorry iam new but should i do like this  @data.update_attributes(:tax_applicable => params[:id => 'tax-btn'])

Comment: `p params` first and check the logs to see what is the actual key you need (:

Comment: i dont know how to do that,but is its possible to populate the id to params <%= form_tag storesignup_is_taxable_path, :method => 
                     :post, :id=>'tax-btn', :remote => true  do  %>  what i want is the id: "tax-btn" to tax_acceptable params!